# Adding an extra geom_hline to the legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data:

```html
df<-read.table (text=" MD   KA  PZ
ko1 65  44
ko2 64  43
ko3 56  42
ko4 71  56
ko5 67  66
ko6 88  64
ko7 44  45
ko8 76  33
ko9 33  22
ko10 84 90
", header=TRUE)
```

I can get only one geom_hline which is called Name1

```html
df1<- df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-1)
df1<-as.data.frame(df1)
gg<- ggplot(df1,aes(MD, value, fill = name))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge", color = "black", width = 1)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
cut <- data.frame(yintercept=20, Name1=factor(20))
gg + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, linetype=Name1),data=cut, show.legend=TRUE)
```

Now I want to add another legend under Name1 which a cut of 70 as Name2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
cut <- data.frame(yintercept=20, Name1=factor(20))
cut2 <- data.frame(yintercept=70, Name2=factor(70))
#Plots
gg + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, linetype=Name1),
             data=cut, show.legend=TRUE,color='red')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, color='70'),
             data=cut2, show.legend=TRUE,linetype=1)+
  scale_color_manual(values='green','Name2')+
  labs(fill='Name',color='Name2',linetype='Name1')+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(order = 1),
         linetype = guide_legend(order = 2,
                                 override.aes = list(color = 'red')), 
           colour = guide_legend(order = 3))
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to add a new scale try this:

```
#Code
gg + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, linetype=Name1),
             data=cut, show.legend=TRUE,color='red')+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, color='70'),
             data=cut2, show.legend=TRUE,linetype=1)+
  scale_color_manual(values='green','Name2')+
  labs(fill='Name',color='Name2',linetype='Name1')+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(order = 1),
         linetype = guide_legend(order = 2,
                                 override.aes = list(color = 'red')), 
         colour = guide_legend(order = 3))+
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color()+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, color='90'),
             data=cut3, show.legend=TRUE,linetype=1)+
  scale_color_manual(values='pink','Name3')
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to get Name1 as red and Name2  as green. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you, I hope you don't mind, I want to add another line say Name3, a cut  40, I struggle to get it, Could  you advise me

Comment: @user330 Hi dear, it is possible let me sketch something for you!

Comment: @user330 I have added an update, but things are complex now, it would be better if you create only one legend for lines.